# Karel Robot: Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, karel

Throughout a maze, I am trying to have my robot put a thing down(putThing) every intersection where one is not already at. RobotSE has the boolean method, isBesideThing(), which I am attempting to use. However, I keep getting the compiling error:

```
MazeIDudItz.java:24: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method isBesideThing()
location: class MazeBot
        if(!this.isBesideThing())
```

I have tried everything that I know how to do. I changed it to a public boolean method ,containing a return value, with no avail. Here is my class extender for RobotSE. This is my first programming class so my apologies ahead of time if I am unclear or what I say does not completely make sense. I know that when I get that error I misspelled something, forgot something, or did not import something. I should only have to import becker.robots.*; since RobotSE is a sub class.

```
class MazeBot extends RobotSE
{

  public MazeBot(City theCity, int str, int ave, Direction dir, int numThings)
  {
    super(theCity, str, ave, dir, numThings);
  }   

  private boolean isAtEndSpot()
  {
    return (this.getAvenue() == 9 && this.getStreet() == 10);   
  }

  public void dontPickThatUp()
  {
    while(!this.isBesideThing())
    {  
      this.putThing();
    }    
  }   

  public void moveCheck()
  {
    if(this.frontIsClear())
    {  
      this.move();
    }
    else
    {   
      this.turnAround();
    }
  }                   

  public void checkRight()
  {
    this.turnRight();
    if (this.frontIsClear())
    {   
      this.moveCheck();
    }
    else
    {  
      this.turnLeft();    
      this.moveCheck();
    }
  }

  public void NavigateMaze()
  {
    while (!this.isAtEndSpot())
    {
      this.checkRight();
    }

  }   
}
```

I appreciate your help and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say to read their [documentation thoroughly.](http://www.learningwithrobots.com/doc/becker/robots/RobotSE.html)

The method signature is

```
public boolean isBesideThing(IPredicate kindOfThing)
```

So you have to match the signature and pass an `IPredicate`.

Comment: I definitely did not read it thoroughly, thank you for your help!